# Concatenate row values based on group by in pyspark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data framew in `pyspark` like below

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('123', '2021-01-01', 1815, 9876), 
('123', '2021-01-01', 1820, 9877) , 
('123', '2021-01-01', 1828, 9878) , 
('123', '2021-02-01', 1815, 9876) , 
('123', '2021-02-01', 1820, 9877) , 
('123', '2021-02-01', 1828, 9878) , 
('223', '2021-01-01', 1815, 9876) , 
('223', '2021-01-01', 1820, 9877) , 
('223', '2021-01-01', 1828, 9878) , 
('223', '2021-02-01', 1815, 9876) , 
('223', '2021-02-01', 1820, 9877) , 
('223', '2021-02-01', 1828, 9878)],['number','date', 'sorter', 'key'])


df.show()
+------+----------+------+----+
|number|      date|sorter| key|
+------+----------+------+----+
|   123|2021-01-01|  1815|9876|
|   123|2021-01-01|  1820|9877|
|   123|2021-01-01|  1828|9878|
|   123|2021-02-01|  1815|9876|
|   123|2021-02-01|  1820|9877|
|   123|2021-02-01|  1828|9878|
|   223|2021-01-01|  1815|9876|
|   223|2021-01-01|  1820|9877|
|   223|2021-01-01|  1828|9878|
|   223|2021-02-01|  1815|9876|
|   223|2021-02-01|  1820|9877|
|   223|2021-02-01|  1828|9878|
+------+----------+------+----+
```

This data frame is sorted based on the `sorter` column

Now using the above data frame I want to create a new data frame. Based on below

```
1) For each group where number and date is same I want to concatenate the `key` value.
2) In each group the first record will have its own `key` as `joined_key`
3) From second record onwards it should have its own `key` and the `joined_key` of previous record
```

`expected result`

```
df1.show()
+------+----------+------+----+---------------+
|number|      date|sorter| key|     Joined_key|
+------+----------+------+----+---------------+
|   123|2021-01-01|  1815|9876|           9876|
|   123|2021-01-01|  1820|9877|      9877~9876|
|   123|2021-01-01|  1828|9878| 9878~9877~9876|
|   123|2021-02-01|  1815|9876|           9876|
|   123|2021-02-01|  1820|9877|      9877~9876|
|   123|2021-02-01|  1828|9878| 9878~9877~9876|
|   223|2021-01-01|  1815|9876|           9876|
|   223|2021-01-01|  1820|9877|      9877~9876|
|   223|2021-01-01|  1828|9878| 9878~9877~9876|
|   223|2021-02-01|  1815|9876|           9876|
|   223|2021-02-01|  1820|9877|      9877~9876|
|   223|2021-02-01|  1828|9878| 9878~9877~9876|
+------+----------+------+----+---------------+
```

I have tried like below but unable to proceed further

```
df1 = df.groupby("number", "date").agg(collect_list('key').alias('joined_key'))
df1.show()
+------+----------+------------------+
|number|      date|        joined_key|
+------+----------+------------------+
|   223|2021-02-01|[9878, 9876, 9877]|
|   123|2021-01-01|[9878, 9876, 9877]|
|   223|2021-01-01|[9878, 9876, 9877]|
|   123|2021-02-01|[9876, 9877, 9878]|
+------+----------+------------------+
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Window` function with some aggregation as below

```
window = Window.partitionBy("number", "date").orderBy("sorter")

df.withColumn("Joined_key", array_join(reverse(collect_list("key").over(window)), "~")) \
.show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+------+----------+------+----+--------------+
|number|date      |sorter|key |Joined_key    |
+------+----------+------+----+--------------+
|223   |2021-02-01|1815  |9876|9876          |
|223   |2021-02-01|1820  |9877|9877~9876     |
|223   |2021-02-01|1828  |9878|9878~9877~9876|
|123   |2021-01-01|1815  |9876|9876          |
|123   |2021-01-01|1820  |9877|9877~9876     |
|123   |2021-01-01|1828  |9878|9878~9877~9876|
|223   |2021-01-01|1815  |9876|9876          |
|223   |2021-01-01|1820  |9877|9877~9876     |
|223   |2021-01-01|1828  |9878|9878~9877~9876|
|123   |2021-02-01|1815  |9876|9876          |
|123   |2021-02-01|1820  |9877|9877~9876     |
|123   |2021-02-01|1828  |9878|9878~9877~9876|
+------+----------+------+----+--------------+
```